# query_posts and only show results if a custom field is not empty

Tags: custom-field, query-posts

How do I `query_posts` and only show results if a custom field is not empty or has a value.

I want to put in a URL in a custom field and only show these pages if there is a URL?

current code but I can't figure out the rest:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '10', 
    'post_type' => 'programmes', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'popularityfig',
    'order'  => 'DESC',
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => '10',
'post_type' => 'programmes',
'meta_key' => 'popularityfig',
'meta_value' => '',
'meta_compare' => '!=',
'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

There're 2 arguments you might want to note in the code: `meta_value` and `meta_compare`. Using `meta_compare` with operator `!=` will exclude posts with empty meta value.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that on codex now?? Why I couldn't see it before I'm not sure!! Thanks again.

Comment: For whatever reason, this kept pulling all of my posts regardless of value. Instead, I used 'meta_value' => array('') and 'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN' and that worked.I created my meta value with the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin and it was just a text field.

Comment: @Tessa This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear if the answer above actually worked for you @erichmond, but it definitely did not for me. Found a solution though. See: [How can I show posts only if meta_value is not empty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/how-can-i-show-posts-only-if-meta-value-is-not-empty)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was not working for me with a text field in Advanced Custom Fields.  It kept pulling all posts once they were saved after the text field was added to the Custom Fields.  I had to do a similar solution to others:

```
$args = array(  
    'meta_key' => 'your_acf_field',
    'meta_value' => array(''),
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN',
);
```