# How to only display posts whose meta_value field is not empty?

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-value

Three people have already tried to solve this, and we're coming up nil. I want to show only posts that have a value in the meta_key 'featured_image'.

So... if 'featured_image' is not empty, show the post. Here's the code:

```
      <ul>
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'featured_image',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
            )
          )
      );
      $ft_pagination = new WP_Query( $args );
      ?>
      <?php while ($ft_pagination->have_posts()) : $ft_pagination->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $ftimage = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'featured_image', TRUE); ?>
        <li>
          <article>
            <a href="">
            <?php if ($ftimage): ?>
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $ftimage; ?>&w=84&h=60" alt="" />
            <?php else: ?>
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/themes/ssv/images/review-default.gif&w=84&h=60" alt="" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
          </article>
        </li>
      <?php
      endwhile;

      wp_reset_query();
      ?>
      </ul>
```

We have tried literally every combination we can think of, the deprecated meta_* options, query_posts, get_posts, instead of WP_Query... Nothing. Printed the select statement, no meta value field is showing. It exists - for the posts (for every post) and it exists in the db.

We've seen every post out there on the topic right now, including these:

[query_posts and only show results if a custom field is not empty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10285/query-posts-and-only-show-results-if-a-custom-field-is-not-empty)

http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Zilch. Please help...

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Sorry Mike, didn't see this — It's 3.1.

Comment: WP 3.5 fixes this problem and lets you use a different compare method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi **@Rob:**

The reason you can't figure out how to do it is because it's not possible, at least not without resorting to SQL. Try adding the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('posts_where','yoursite_posts_where',10,2);
function yoursite_posts_where($where,$query) {
  global $wpdb;
  $new_where = " TRIM(IFNULL({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value,''))<>'' ";
  if (empty($where))
    $where = $new_where;
  else
    $where = "{$where} AND {$new_where}";
  return $where;
}
```

If you have custom `'featured_image'` fields with empty values the above will filter them out. If you problem is something else, we'll have to see what your data looks like to solve it.

One thing I'm curious about; how did you get empty values for `'featured_image'`?  The admin UI in WordPress 3.1 does its best to keep you from entering empty values.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank god... so it's not just us. That's good to know, I suppose. Thank you @MikeSchinkel - They really ought to put that in the codex... Looking forward to the explanation. Thanks!!

Comment: @Rob - So I was going off my 3.0 knowledge and now I'm testing it in 3.1 and it does seem to work. I have two posts and one with a `featured_image` custom field and your query works fine. What are you finding? Is there a chance your query is loading posts that do have a `featured_image` custom field but where the value for that field is empty?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - No kidding? Yes, that's exactly what it's doing — every post has the featured_image field, they're just not all set. It's loading up all posts anyway.

Comment: @Rob - See my updated answer.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Thank you! It seems to be working perfectly, after setting the post_type in the query also. The empty values are purposeful — not every post has this featured image (and I know about the post thumbnail, it's just not a good option for this site). Thanks so much!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I stand corrected - it works on the queries that I wanted it to, but it's causing 404's everywhere else. Single post pages, archives... :o\ Any ideas?

Comment: In the code sample in your question above, try putting the `add_filter()` call just before your `WP_Query()` call, then put `remove_filter('posts_where','yoursite_posts_where');` just before you call `wp_reset_query()`.

Comment: That code checks ALL custom fields to see if ANY of them are empty? What if I want the query to only check for one special field and see if that is empty no matter what the other ones are?

Answer (score 65):

This seems to work for getting the value into the query, not sure about whether it pulls valid results though..

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'some_key',
        'value'   => array(''),
        'compare' => 'NOT IN'
    )
)
```

Not had time to create fields to test the results, but i've been watching queries i've worked with today and noticed `NOT IN` will happily take an empty array.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but for those trying this apparoach, it works with `'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'` instead of `'NOT IN`'

Comment: Surely more efficient to use != instead of not in or not like.  Same as http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10286/32863 (that is about meta keys, but same principle)

Comment: Even cleaner solution: like Adam stated already. Is to use: 
`'value'   => '',     
'compare' => '!='    `

Comment: If you need to check to make sure it's not an empty array... `'value'   => array('', array(), serialize(array())),  'compare' => 'NOT IN'`

Answer (score 27):

This is an old question, but it seems Wordpress has fixed this "missing feature": now, according to [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments) is possible to check for existence (or non-existence) of the meta key, like this

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'featured_image',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS', //or "NOT EXISTS", for non-existance of this key
    )
)
```

This is available as of WP >= 3.5.

Comment: `EXISTS` will show empty values which is not what we're after here. The best solution is `'value' => '', 'compare' => '!=' ` as far as my testing goes.

Comment: @Ben That's exactly what the OP tried, but without any success, it seems. I added my solution to make sure people passing by searching for a method to retrieve posts based on existence of meta_key could find it. Since the value of a meta can be "something", "empty" or "null" (in case the meta doesn't exist), probably the best solution would be to merge the two options with an "AND" relation

Answer (score 15):

If you want the meta value to exist and have some value other than an empty string:

```
      'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
          'key' => 'some_key',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ],
        [
          'key' => 'some_key',
          'compare' => '!=',
          'value' => ''
        ]
      ]
```

Comment: This is the only 100% correct answer according to my tests.

Comment: I tried all the solutions & this one is only worked.

Answer (score 9):

This is the query that worked for me. Very similar to the comparison in t31os's answer from 2011, but because the meta key/value is just a simple textstring, it doesn't need to be a meta_query array.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,//replaced 'showposts' in version 2.1
    'meta_key' => 'featured_image',
    'meta_value' => array(''),
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN'
);
```

For whatever reason, using `'meta_value' => ''` (set to an empty string) and `'meta_compare' => '!='` or `'meta_compare' => 'NOT LIKE'` still pulled all posts for me, but it probably has something to do with the fact that I created my meta value using the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin.

While using `EXISTS` may work, it does not check if the value is empty or not, so it'd still pull posts that have the meta field even if the meta value is blank or empty.

[Read more about custom field parameters in the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters). Possible values for `meta_compare`:

- `=`
- `!=`
- `>` - works with numeric, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` meta value types
- `>=` - works with numeric, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` meta value types
- `<` - works with numeric, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` meta value types
- `<=` - works with numeric, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` meta value types
- `LIKE` - can work with an array of meta values
- `NOT LIKE` - can work with an array of meta values
- `IN` - meta value should be an array of values
- `NOT IN` - meta value should be an array of values
- `BETWEEN` - works with numeric, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` meta value types as well as an array of values
- `NOT BETWEEN` - works with numeric, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` meta value types as well as an array of values
- `EXISTS` - no need to specify a meta value for WP versions 3.9 and above
- `NOT EXISTS` - no need to specify a meta value for WP versions 3.9 and above
- `REGEXP`
- `NOT REGEXP`
- `RLIKE`

Answer (score 4):

Am i missing something?

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => "featured_image"
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

?>
```

Won't that do it?

Comment: Edit:  from the codex: ```$query = new WP_Query( 'meta_key=featured_image' );```  look here:http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: First, you can always [edit] a question or answer instead of adding a comment. Second: Don't **misuse** answers instead of comments.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @kaiser - seems to me like he was answering. He's not asking if his code is valid, but I suppose sort of sarcastically answering the question with what he believes will work.

Comment: @Nathan This is what comments are for.

Comment: @kaiser, Comments are for posting answers and code? How do you post code in a comment?

Comment: @Nathan I was referring to the sarcastic part of the answer. The code should be an answer – including some explanation.

Comment: There was a bug in WordPress but now it's fixed.  This is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in WP 3.2-alpha:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15292

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this may help. You could always use the 'EMPTY' or 'NOT EMPTY' comparator like so:

```
       'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
          'key' => 'your_key',
          'compare' => 'NOT EMPTY',
        ],
     
      ]
```

Use this with one of my checkbox ACF fields which seems to work really well. In my case, I was doing the opposite of yourself and some of the posts I was querying didn't have an entry for this meta field so I simply added the NOT EXISTS option as a second comparison.

Querying posts that either did not contain the meta field or contained an empty field:

```
 'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
          'key' => 'your_key',
          'compare' => 'NOT EXIST',
        ],
        [
          'key' => 'your_key',
          'compare' => 'EMPTY',
        ],
     
      ]
```

Comment: I can't find the documentation for 'EMPTY' and 'NOT EMPTY'. Do you have a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

So I had this problem specifically when using ACF & when using a field that held a multiple select that had previously had been populated and now was empty.

I had the issue that:

```
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
       'key' => 'field_name',
       'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),    
    array(
      'key' => 'field_name',
      'value' => '',
      'compare' => '!='
    ),
```

Was returning all the posts whether the meta was empty or not?

So instead I looked to see if the field contained a double quote:

```
    'key' => 'field_name',
    'value' => '"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

As ACF uses double quotes in an array structure for multi selects stored in the DB.

Hope this helps someone who has fallen into the same trap as I :-)

Answer (score -4):

```
!has_featured_image();
```

one liner ftw.