# Set Pagination count according to post count

Tags: pagination, count

i have created a php template for a page and displaying posts from my custom post type, but i am skiping posts according to the followed condition.

so this is my page template code.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array( 
         'post_type' => 'custom-post-type', 
         'paged'     => $paged,
         'order_by'  => 'DESC',
         'posts_per_page' => 10, //my posts count, but on page post count mismatch
         'meta_value' => 'someMetaVale',   
      );
$query= WP_query($args);
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
   $meta_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID,'some_meta_key',true);
    $post_args = array( 
         'post_type' => 'post', 
         'posts_per_page' => 1,
         'meta_value' => $meta_value,   
      );
       $result = get_posts($post_args);
       if(!empty($result[0]->ID)) // here is my condition where i am skipping posts.
       {
             the_title(); //here i am printing post title
       }
   }
 <div class="dt-pagination-nav">
                <?php if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) 

            { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1 

             ?>
            <?php
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

            echo paginate_links( array('base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
              'format'          => 'page/%#%',
              'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
              'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
              'add_fragment'    => '',
            ));
            ?>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>`
```

Problem arises is that i have mismatch of posts in page, because of posts that i am skipping, so please suggest a solution for which i can skip posts as well and also make my count correct

Comment: Why you are skipping the posts? And why you are checking posts again with same meta_value that you get in loop?

Comment: Hi!
I am skipping posts of same meta value becoz these posts are of different types.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try resolving this in the wp query with meta query.
[This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/how-can-i-show-posts-only-if-meta-value-is-not-empty) might help you.